# tableadapter problem between dev and production server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, tableadapter

I have a problem when trying to create a new sproc for a tableadapter. On my development server, Visual Studio is using my windows login; domain name/ username. When I try and create the same tableadapter sproc on our production server, Visual Studio uses "dbo" for the db connection user ID. This is what I want for both environments. Any suggestions as to what permission issues might be going on between the two servers? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're having?

Answer (score 0):

Your username has sysadmin rights in production.

Anyone with sysadmin at the SQL instance/login level is dbo at the database/user level.
In development, it only has db_owner or ddladmin in the database but is not sysadmin.

Anyway:

- Why aren't you using the schema when creating objects? like: "CREATE PROC **dbo.**uspFoo"
- Why are you deploying to production from VS?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I was able to resolve it with this info.